# Using a YouTube developer key to pull media keywords

Tags: youtube, tags, youtube-api, keyword

Recently YouTube changed their policy with regard to showing tags on the front-end.

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

This also results in API calls that output empty *media:keywords* arrays. I can pull videos and meta but can no longer pull the associated tags, which I use to post featured content. I own the account, and can verify the tags are in place.

YouTube tells me that I should still have this functionality as long as I authenticate. Oauth2 seems like massive overkill here. Instead, I am including the key query parameter in the original request URL (that was working prior to the change in policy) as oulined [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Developer_Key):

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MYACCT/uploads?orderby=updated&key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull the tags for my videos. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be completely wrong, but unfortunately I think you are going to need Oauth2, and I don't know if even it will do exactly what you're hoping -- the paradigm is not that you provide a key to expose your tags to anyone that you want, but that individual users must authorize their tags to be exposed to the app (and that authorization isn't persistent). In other words, you can set up a login form so whoever logs in will be able to use your app to pull their own videos' tags, but still not those of others (even yours).

The general idea is that video tags are now being treated as private data, available only to the users who created the data and exposed only when then give explicit permission.

If I am wrong, someone please correct me!

Comment: So I decided to abandon the old ways and simply make a new YouTube playlist for my featured content. YouTube tags are dead to me. Thanks jlmcdonald for pulling me out of that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jlmcdonald seems to have a point. Developer tags can be retrieved, but only from authenticated HTTP requests because they are private to particular developer account.